# Integrals $\int\limits _{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{1+\cos^2x},~~\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1-\cos^2x}{1+\cos^2x}dx$

Tags: integration

> Evaluate the definite integrals:
>
> $$I_1=\int\limits _{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{1+\cos^2x},~~I_2=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1-\cos^2x}{1+\cos^2x}dx.$$

Thanks for the help.

**Attempt.** The classic substitution $\tan(\frac{x}{2})=t$ yields
$$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2},~\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ and seems to be making the integral more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite trivial that $I_2=2I_1-\frac{\pi}{4}$, hence we may just compute $I_1$ through the substitution $x=\arctan(t)$, leading to:

$$ I_1 = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{t^2+1}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+t^2}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{2+t^2}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}$$
pretty easily.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

1. Substitute $u=\tan(x)$ and $\text{d}u=\sec^2(x)\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\int\frac{1}{1+\cos^2(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{\sec^2(x)}{1+\sec^2(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{\sec^2(x)}{2+\tan^2(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{2+u^2}\space\text{d}u$$
2. Substitute $s=\cot(x)$ and $\text{d}s=-\csc^2(x)\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\int\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}\cdot\frac{-\csc^4(x)}{-\csc^4(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$
   $$\int\frac{\csc^2(x)}{1+3\cot^2(x)+2\cot^4(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{1+s^2}\space\text{d}s-2\int\frac{1}{1+2s^2}\space\text{d}s$$

So, the answers are:

- $$\text{I}_1=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\approx0.43521$$
- $$\text{I}_2=\sqrt{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}\approx0.0850216$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
I_1=\int\limits _{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{1+\cos^2x}=\int\limits _{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{\sin^2 x+2\cos^2x}=\int\limits _{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{dx}{\tan^2x+2}\cdot \frac{dx}{\cos^2x}
$$ similarly
$$
I_2=\int\limits _{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{1+\cos^2x}\:dx=\int\limits _{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{\tan^2x}{(\tan^2x+1)\cdot(\tan^2x+2)}\cdot \frac{dx}{\cos^2x}.
$$